# Pokemon TM upgrade from evolve chart

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

*Blastoise* doesn't normally learn **Blizzard** nor **Ice Beam**, by leveling up.
But if you teach it **Bubble beam** when it was still a *Squirtle*, it will learn the two said moves.

It seems that Bubble Beam also gets an upgrade from pokemon that evolves thus allowing you to learn those two other moves a pokemon wouldn't normally learn by simply leveling up.

With that said, is there any sites that shows a list of these moves upgrade from evolving pokemon?

EDIT: This was on the generation 1 (Pokemon yellow to be exact)

Comment: You might want to indicate the specific game or generation you're talking about.

Comment: I've *never* heard of learned attacks changing based on what attacks the pokemon already knows. I'll reiterate Toomai - what specific game or generation are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

[Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Blastoise_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_I_learnset#By_leveling_up) indicates that **Blizzard** and **Ice Beam** can not be learned by a gen 1 Blastoise by levelling up, at all. It can only be taught those moves by using a TM.

There are some pokemon who learn a move by levelling up in some of their basic evolutions that they cannot learn in a higher evolution. For example [Raichu](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Raichu_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_I_learnset#By_leveling_up) cannot learn Slam, but it can have the move if you levelled it up to level 20 as a pikachu before evolving. This is the closest equivalent to that which you describe.

Comment: I will try my best to replicate this situation again. My savefile indeed has Blastoise learn both moves even though I only have him learn the Bubble Beam TM and Surf HM.

Comment: @patcol are you playing the actual (cartridge) game, or a ROM?

Comment: Actual cartridge, bad news though. There seems to be some problem on my cart. The cart doesn't seems to be able to hold any saves files anymore and whenever I turn off or reset the game, the save file get lost too.

Comment: @patcol The internal battery on the cart is dead. I believe it uses some standard battery, so you should be able to buy a replacement, open the cart, and replace the battery